Gazebo GUI using WSL for ROS Humble and VCXSRV showing a blank screen
I am a beginner who has just started using RoS2. I made my first workspace this week itself. I am having an issue regarding Gazebo where opening the GUI just gives me a black screen with none of the features or buttons doing anything. The real time factor switches between 0.97 to 0.98 and vice versa. Really annoying and I have tried almost all solutions available online. Any help?
